# Canon PIXMA MX870 can't use papers from the cassette tray

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I've successfully added my printer via Ubuntu 12.04 default drivers, but it seems the driver doesn't support using papers from the cassette tray even if I set the default preference to use the cassette only. Each time I print the document, I always check this setting, as well as the status of the cassette (there are at least 10 pieces of papers inside).

Screenshot: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8128/screenshotfrom201211191.png

The warning message I receive from the printer is that there is no paper at the REAR tray! I don't have such issues with my Windows 7 Pro.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing with my Canon MG5150... I had printed something, and the next print order, all it wanted to do is print from the rear tray.

I removed the printer from: system settings -> printer, and then added it again. Now it seems to work fine...

Comment: I'll try this... thanks for sharing. I'll get back to you with my own result of the same procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Read this thread. I found it useful.

ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475336‎

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @datguy, Welcome to AskUbuntu and thanks for your contribution. You may want to read the "About" page at the top near the search bar. You cannot use a link as the answer. You may use links as references, but you must answer the question with your words. This answer should be changed before other users see and give you downvotes.